# how can i input 2 digit number in assembly emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
mov ah,01h
int 21h
```

I know this is how you enter a one digit number or a char, but how can i enter for example the number 38.
Thank you

Comment: Read two digits and make a number from them.

Comment: Do you mean I should write the above code twice?

Comment: That's an option. And then assemple the two digits you read into a number.

Comment: Consider using function `0Ah` instead of `01h`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
.model small
.data
.code

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax 

mov dl, 10  
mov bl, 0         

scanNum:

      mov ah, 01h
      int 21h

      cmp al, 13   ; Check if user pressed ENTER KEY
      je  exit 

      mov ah, 0  
      sub al, 48   ; ASCII to DECIMAL

      mov cl, al
      mov al, bl   ; Store the previous value in AL

      mul dl       ; multiply the previous value with 10

      add al, cl   ; previous value + new value ( after previous value is multiplyed with 10 )
      mov bl, al

      jmp scanNum    

exit:

      mov ah, 04ch   
      int 21h

 end
```

Comment: If you're going to loop for an arbitrary number of digits, it would make more sense to get a 16-bit result so you can handle inputs up to 65535.  You'd have to change your function to keep the `10` somewhere else because `mul dx` writes DX:AX.   (Or do it with shift and add instead of `mul` so you can leave AX and DX unused for `int 21h` calls.)

Answer (score -2):

```
.MODEL SMALL
 .STACK 100H

 .DATA
    PROMPT_1  DB  'Enter the First digit : $'
    PROMPT_2  DB  'Enter the Second digit : $'
    PROMPT_3  DB  'Sum of First and Second digit : $'

 .CODE
   MAIN PROC
     MOV AX, @DATA                ; initialize DS
     MOV DS, AX

     LEA DX, PROMPT_1             ; load and display the PROMPT_1
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     MOV AH, 1                    ; read a character\\digit
     INT 21H

     MOV BL, AL                   ; save First digit in BL in ASCII code
     SUB BL, 30H

     MOV AH, 2                    ; carriage return
     MOV DL, 0DH
     INT 21H

     MOV DL, 0AH                  ; line feed
     INT 21H

     LEA DX, PROMPT_2             ; load and display the PROMPT_2
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     MOV AH, 1                    ; read a character
     INT 21H

     MOV BH, AL                   ; save Second digit in BH in ASCII CODE
     SUB BH, 30H

     MOV AH, 2                    ; carriage return
     MOV DL, 0DH
     INT 21H

     MOV DL, 0AH                  ; line feed
     INT 21H

     LEA DX, PROMPT_3             ; load and display the PROMPT_3
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     ADD BL, BH                   ; add First and Second digit
     ADD BL, 30H                  ; convert ASCII to DECIMAL code

     MOV AH, 2                    ; display the character
     MOV DL, BL     
     INT 21H

     MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS
     INT 21H
   MAIN ENDP
 END MAIN
```

Comment: This sums 2 separate 1-digit numbers; it doesn't read a 2-digit number and convert it to an integer from 0..99 with `digit1 * 10 + digit2`